# I am using Filebeat->logstash->eleasticsearch->kibana

Tags: logstash

We implemented the filebeat,logstash,elastic with Kibana dashboard to view the opertational Log contents. I have a situation where i am getting logs from from different service like this: For e.g) a single Service we collected the operational log like this format.

```
timestamp <uniquerID> entry: ProcessAPI{AddEmployee} :hostname
timestamp <uniquerID> send: UserAPI{ValidateUser} :hostname
timestamp <uniquerID> receive: UserAPI{ValidateUser} :hostname
timestamp <uniquerID> send: AccountAPI{ValidateAccount} :hostname
timestamp <uniquerID> receive: AccountAPI{ValidateAccount} :hostname
timestamp <uniquerID> exit: ProcessAPI{AddEmployee} :hostname

I want to combine these log line to a single line like below format:

timestamp <uniquerID> Exit:ProcessAPI{AddEmployee} :hostname| UserAPI{ValidateUser} :hostname |  AccountAPI{ValidateAccount} :hostname

Each log line has associated parent service name in the source field.Is there any solution we can adopt to achive this.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell logstash that you have a multi-line log format using the multi-line codec as part of your input.  It can be complex and would depend on the specific format of your log file entries to get the correct setup of the codec.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html